# How to call Lua Functions with AluminumLua in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, lua, aluminumlua

I'm just learning about Lua and trying to integrate it with C# and mono (on Linux). After some looking around, I found AluminumLua as a wrapper to do so.

I've successfully being able to call from lua to C#, but I can't see the way to call from C# to lua:

lua (test.lua):

```
HelloWorld()

function print_test()
    print("hi")
    return 1
end
```

C#

```
var context = new LuaContext ();
context.AddBasicLibrary ();
context.AddIoLibrary ();

context.SetGlobal ("HelloWorld", LuaObject.FromDelegate(new Action(HelloWorld)));

var parser = new LuaParser (context, "test.lua");
parser.Parse ();

...

public static void HelloWorld() {
     Console.Write("HelloWorld");
}
```

That's cool, but... How can I call the function "print_test", get its output result from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source, `LuaContext` has a `Get` method which returns a `LuaObject`. After you have a reference to that `LuaObject` you can try to turn it into a `LuaFunction` using `AsFunction` and `IsFunction`.

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
// ...
var print_test = context.Get("print_test");
if (print_test.IsFunction)
{
  print_test.AsFunction()(null);
}
else
{
  Console.Write("print_test not a lua function!");
}
// ...
```